# How To select Indexes From a specific Table from MS access 2007

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

i want to select list of Indexes and put it in a datatable in viusal basic and iam using oledb to connect to 2002-2003 database format (.mdb)

like ,

```
Dim con as new oledb.oledbconnection 
Dim conAdapter as oledb.oledbDataAdabter
Dim Table as new datatable

conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='MY DATABESE LOCATION';"
conn = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM 'what i want to select table1 indexes'", conn)
connAdabter.fill(Table)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OleDbConnection` has a method that returns SCHEMA information about Tables, Indexes etc...

```
 Dim connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='MY DATABESE LOCATION';"
 Using con as new oledb.oledbconnection(connectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim indexes = con.GetSchema("Indexes").Select("TABLE_NAME = 'yourTableNameHere'").CopyToDataTable()
    For Each row in indexes.Rows
        Console.WriteLine(row("INDEX_NAME"))
        Console.WriteLine(row("COLUMN_NAME"))
        Console.WriteLine(row("PRIMARY_KEY"))
    Next

End Using
```

[See MSDN OleDbConnection.GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135981(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Very very much it works i was searching on it for month